# Django form choices maipulation

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I have done a research on how to manipulate django form choices but i have not seen what i am looking for. Maybe i am not doing my research very well.

Model.py sample

```
class CurrentStudent(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(PostGraduate, unique = True)
    Current = 'Current'
    Graduated = 'Graduated'
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((Current, 'Current'), (Graduated, 'Graduated'))
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=Current)
    project_proposal = models.FileField(upload_to='Post Graduate/proposal/', blank = True,)
    project = models.FileField(upload_to='Post Graduate/project/', blank = True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.surname
```

If a student choose current in the status field, the student will not be able to fill project field but can fill the remaining fields. But if the student choose graduate, the project field and other fields will appear for the student to fill and it cant be empty.

Is it possible in django? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

with what I see from your code this can be done . you can take a loot at [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) 
an example of it would be like this

```
def view_function(request):
Current = "Current"
if request.POST == Current:
    #something 
else:
    #another
```

sorry cant go furthur .
answering at work